Excel - Conditional Formatting on Times
I am trying to use conditional formatting to highlight the top 5 of a column of times in different colours. The cells are formatted as hh:mm:ss, but using the 'Large' or 'Small' functions this does not seem to work. Ideally, I need a formula to work on the lowest value time selecting the required fill colour, and then I can duplicate the formula selecting the next lowest with a different colour.
Please let me know if you have a formula which I can use to achieve this.
Thanks,
Kev

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please edit your question to include a small representative data sample as text which can be copy/pasted; a screenshot of your expected outcome from that data; what you have tried and what you mean by "not seem to work".

Isn't the maximum or minimum of conditional formatting directly getting the result you want?

How is the data formatted? Can you share a mockup of the table? What IS getting selected when you use those Large and Small functions?

There are several ways to do this, but it cannot be fully automated.
The easiest way is to use the Bottom 5 rule, but then all 5 cells will be the same color.
The second way is to apply a color scale, choosing the lower limit as the minimum of the range, the midpoint as the formula:
=SMALL(range, 3)
and the proper color.
Maximum as a formula:
=SMALL(range, 5)
and the right color. In this way, we define 3 colors, and the other 2 will be automatically selected as intermediate.
range represents your actual formatting range.
To this must be added a rule masking values higher than these five. This rule must have a higher priority than the color scale. Formula (in my example) is:
=F2>SMALL($F$2:$F$11, 5)
Color: no color.
The third way is to define 5 rules, separately for each color. For example, the rule:
=H2=SMALL($H$2:$H$11, 1)
In the range of H2:H11 and corresponding analogous rules with numbers 2, 3, 4, 5 and other colors.

